# JsonProperty seems to not working on a windows azure app service

Tags: c#, json, azure, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an application hosted in Microsoft Azure cloud. This application is an app service.
I currently have some issues with a JSON serialization. The received JSON is not on the correct format.
My application is an ASP.NET MVC6.
Basically, I have a front, who is receiving a JSON value from a controller (server side).

**C# Server side method:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("domain/search")]
public IActionResult Search(string sn)
{
    // DOING MY STUFF
    ICollection<MyModel> myobject
    return new ObjectResult(myobject);
}
```

**Model class:**

```
public class MyModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sn", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "state", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public AStateTypeModel? State { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    .
    .
    ETC
    .
    .
}
```

**Correct JSON to receive:**

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"806c76b5-guid-guid-guid-guid",
      "sn":"X00000000000",
      "state":"AState",
      .
      .
      ETC
      .
      .
   }
]
```

When I am launching the application in local mode, everything is fine. I have the correct JSON values and property names.
But on Azure, the front receive an incorrect JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":"806c76b5-guid-guid-guid-guid",
      "SerialNumber":"X00000000000",
      "Description":null,
      "State":1,
      .
      .
      ETC
      .
      .
   }
]
```

I thought it was a difference of package versions between my local and those present on the Azure server, but everything looks fine.
The `JsonProperty` attribute seems to be ignored.
I am currently using Windows Azure SDK 2.8, Newtonsoft 9.0.1. and AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0:

**Dependencies:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Owin": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis": "2.2.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebSockets.Server": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
  }
```

I don't know if I have some troubles with the `JsonFormatter` or something like that...
What's wrong?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I close the post, because since yesterday, it's working normally.
I did nothing excepts playing with the package version of:
- Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
- Newtonsoft.Json
I would like to find why, but I have a lack of clues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that your enum is serialized as `string` in local mode and as `int` when deployed to Azure. You could put a `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` attribute over your enum to ensure, that it is serialized as as `string`.

If you want to `string` serialization per default, you could set the Json.NET default properties like so:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters =
    {
        new StringEnumConverter
        {
            CamelCaseText = true
        }
    }
};
```

To ensure that your controller does use Json.NET, you can overload the standard `Json()` method in the controller and use `Json(myobject)` instead of `ObjectResult(myobject)`:

```
protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
{
    return new JsonNetResult(base.Json(data, contentType, contentEncoding, behavior));
}

private class JsonNetResult : JsonResult
{
    public JsonNetResult()
    {
        this.ContentType = "application/json";
    }

    public JsonNetResult(JsonResult existing)
    {
        this.ContentEncoding = existing.ContentEncoding;
        this.ContentType = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(existing.ContentType) ? existing.ContentType : "application/json";
        this.Data = existing.Data;
        this.JsonRequestBehavior = existing.JsonRequestBehavior;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        if ((this.JsonRequestBehavior == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet) && string.Equals(context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            base.ExecuteResult(context);                            // Delegate back to allow the default exception to be thrown
        }

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = this.ContentType;

        if (this.ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = this.ContentEncoding;
        }

        if (this.Data != null)
        {
            // Replace with your favourite serializer.
            new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer().Serialize(response.Output, this.Data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issues are not only on enum but on all JSON properties name.
I would like to have

    [  
        {  
            "id":"806c76b5-guid-guid-guid-guid",
            "sn":"X00000000000"
        }
    ]

instead of 

    [  
        {  
            "Id":"806c76b5-guid-guid-guid-guid",
            "SerialNumber":"X00000000000"
        }
    ]

Comment: Now I see. I updated the answer... maybe azure is not using Json.NET at all so you try to overload the default Json response method,